# Creating data structure containing factors and matrices

Tags: r, data-structures, matrix

I have 6 matrices of size 100*50 (e.g. m1-m6) and 6 matrices of size 100*100 (m7-m12). these matrices are nested withing two factors as F and G. I want to create a data structure that reflects this design:

```
F1  G1  m1
F1  G2  m2
F1  G3  m3
F1  G1  m4
F1  G2  m5
F1  G3  m6
F2  G1  m7
F2  G2  m8
F2  G3  m9
F2  G1  m10
F2  G2  m11
F2  G3  m12
```

I want to use these structure for ANOVA and plotting the results. Each matrix consists of values over 100 replications. The m1-m12 matrices are stored in `csv` files.So, I need to import the matrices and create the data structure.I tried `array` or `list` but I couldn't find an efficient and correct way for doing that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array`, First I create data structure:

```
A1 = array(0,dim=c(100,50,6))
A2 = array(0,dim=c(100,100,6))
```

I assume you have 2 list of file names , `list_files1` and `list_files2`:

```
lapply(seq_along(list_files1),function(x){
  A1[,,x] <- read.csv(list_files1[[x]])
})
lapply(seq_along(list_files2),function(x){
  A2[,,x] <- read.csv(list_files2[[x]])
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.What do you mean by `list file`?How can I create it in R?Also, the `A1` and `A2` has to be combined containing factors.How could it be done?

Comment: @Amin I can if you add an example of the expected output. For example edit your question and add an example of the expected output , using 2 matrix of size 2*2 and 2*4.

Comment: I want to compare matrices based on the factors.In other words, each matrix has occurred under a specific condition defibed bt factors so factors are indicators of experiment's condition for each matrix.